# SQL replace every other comma with a semicolon

Tags: sql, sql-server, replace

I have a bunch of strings that should have been stored as value pairs but were not. Now I need to replace every other comma with a semicolon to make them pairs. Hoping to find a simple way of doing this, but there might not be one.

ex:

> -1328.89,6354.22,-1283.94,6242.96,-1172.68,6287.91,-1217.63,6399.18

should be:

> -1328.89,6354.22;-1283.94,6242.96;-1172.68,6287.91;-1217.63,6399.18

Comment: Are all the numbers negative or is it only because of your specific example?

Comment: do you mean every other comma, or every third comma ?

Comment: You have a database with a single VarChar column that contains strings like “-1328.89,6354.22,-1283.94,6242.96,...”? You’ve got bigger problems than “every other comma”; your data violates first-normal form. You need to split the column into multiple rows with one value per row.

Comment: BWS-Yeah, it's every other comma, sorry, fix the 'Should be' value

Comment: The numbers are not always negative.  They are coordinates so sometimes negative, sometimes positive.

Comment: PATINDEX boring code in 3,2,1

Comment: which version of tsql are you using ?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2005 - 9.00.5000.00 (X64) 
 Dec 10 2010 10:38:40 
 Copyright (c) 1988-2005 Microsoft Corporation
 Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)
Compatibility Level: 90

Comment: Are there always four pairs?  Or does the size vary?

Comment: The number of pairs will vary

Comment: I weep for your table structure. You definitely need to change the way your database is storing data as this is a mess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
create function f_tst(@a varchar(100)) -- use right size of field
returns varchar(100) -- make sure you use the right size of field
begin
declare @pos int = charindex(',', @a) + 1
;while 0 < charindex(',', @a, @pos) 
select @a = stuff(@a, charindex(',', @a, @pos), 1, ';'), 
@pos = charindex(',', @a, charindex(',', @a, @pos + 1)) + 1

return @a
end

go

declare @a varchar(100) = '-1328.89,6354.22,-1283.94,6242.96,-1172.68,6287.91,-1217.63,6399.18'
select dbo.f_tst(@a)
```

Or in your example

```
update <table>
set <field> = dbo.f_tst(<field>)
```

Comment: Great solution and uses the fewest lines of code, something I always look for in a 'simple' solution.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Surely not so simple as you want, but a CHARINDEX/SUBSTRING solution:

```
Declare @input nvarchar(max) = '-1328.89,6354.22,-1283.94,6242.96,-1172.68,6287.91,-1217.63,6399.18'

Declare @i int = 0, @t int = 0, @isComma bit = 1
Declare @output nvarchar(max) = ''
Select @i = CHARINDEX(',', @input)
While (@i > 0)
Begin
    Select @output = @output + SUBSTRING(@input, @t + 1, @i - @t - 1) + CASE @isComma WHEN 1 THEN ',' ELSE ';' END
    Select @t = @i
    Select @i = CHARINDEX(',', @input, @i + 1), @isComma = 1 - @isComma
End
Select @output = @output + SUBSTRING(@input, @t + 1, 1000)
Select @output
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with a combination of dynamic sql and for xml:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
set @sql = '-1328.89,6354.22,-1283.94,6242.96,-1172.68,6287.91,-1217.63,6399.18'
set @sql = '
    select replace((select cast(value as varchar(50)) +
    cast(case row_number() over(order by sort)%2 when 0 then '','' else '';'' end as char(1))
    from (select ' + replace(@sql,',',' value,1 sort union all select ') + ',1 sort)q
    for xml path(''''))+''||'','',||'','''') YourUpdatedValue'
exec(@sql)
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in a single query:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (id int, col varchar(max))
INSERT @t VALUES
(1,'-1328.89,6354.22,-1283.94,6242.96,-1172.68,6287.91,-1217.63,6399.18'),
(2,'-4534.89,454.22,-1123.94,2932.96,-1872.68,327.91,-417.63,635.18')

;WITH t AS (
  SELECT id, i % 2 x, i / 2 y, val
  FROM @t
  CROSS APPLY (SELECT CAST('<a>'+REPLACE(col,',','</a><a>')+'</a>' AS xml) xml1 ) t1
  CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT
      n.value('for $i in . return count(../*[. << $i])', 'int') i,
      n.value('.','varchar(max)') AS val
    FROM xml1.nodes('a') x(n)
  ) t2
)
SELECT id, y, [0]+','+[1] col
FROM t
PIVOT(MAX([val]) FOR x IN ([0],[1])) t3
ORDER BY id, y


id  y   val
----------------------------
1   0   -1328.89,6354.22
1   1   -1283.94,6242.96
1   2   -1172.68,6287.91
1   3   -1217.63,6399.18
2   0   -4534.89,454.22
2   1   -1123.94,2932.96
2   2   -1872.68,327.91
2   3   -417.63,635.18
```

Comment: Thanks Anon, this will be perfect if we ever decide to break the data out to another table.